# I have got two ids where after appending the first id to the url and clicking on accept button i need to append the 2nd id to the Url and not able to

Tags: java, selenium

I have got two ids where after appending the first id to the url and clicking on accept button i need to append the 2nd id to the Url and not able to Append the 2nd id to the URL.

Below is the My Code: Any Leads:

String confirmationURL = "https://test-website/#/email?type=proposal";
List newurls = new ArrayList();

```
            //get the link and append the lastdemandid
    
            
            newurls.add(confirmationURL + "&id=" + getDemandId1()); **This is the firstid and works fine**
            
            
            driver.get(newurls.get(0));

            
            String AcceptbtElem = buttonXpath_replace.replace("XXXX","Accept");
            clickOnButton(driver, AcceptbtElem);
            
            inputEntry(driver, ManualOverrideRemarksinputXpath_Replace.replace("XXXX", "Comments"), formEntryMap.get("Comments"));
            
            String SubmitbtnElem = buttonXpath_replace.replace("XXXX", "Submit");
            clickOnButton(driver, SubmitbtnElem);
            
           System.out.println("Get the DemadId2:"+ CommonUseUtil.getDemandId2());
            
            
            newurls.add(confirmationURL + "&id=" + CommonUseUtil.getDemandId2()); = This is the place where the issue is - It appends only the first Id to the URL and is not appending the second Id ....Second id value appears as i Printed to check that....


            
            
            driver.get(newurls.get(0));
```

Any inputs on this

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, for better questions in the future please express what kind of error or in what way it's "not working".

I also don't have the code for what `CommonUseUtil` is so I'm not sure what type `.getDemandId2()` is returning. It looks like you need a `String` so make sure it's doing that! You can make it easy by setting it to a `String` var.

Lastly, it looks like `newurls` is an ArrayList. So if you `.add` to it then `newurls.get(0)` will be the first url, the one that works. And `newurls.get(1)` will be the second url. So if you're trying to call that new second url you should be calling `newurls.get(1)`.

I know this is a late answer to your question but I hope it helps.